# How do I change the color of each element on scroll using jQuery offset()?

Tags: jquery, navigation, scroll, offset

I wrote a script that makes my navigation stick to the top of the screen once it passes a certain point. It works great so I decided to try to write another script that highlights the section on the nav as it reaches the section in the page. Only problem is I estimated the amount of pixels to each section. I know I can use the jQuery .offset() to make this more precise but I'm not sure how to write that within my current script. Below is the relevant HTML and javaScript. I would really appreciate any solid suggestions. Thanks.

```
<nav class='pink-bar'><!--<img class='nav' src='assets/nav.png' alt='navigation bar' />  -->
     <div class='content'>
            <ul class='menu'>
                <li id='menu-1'>Home</li>
                <li id='menu-2'>Buy The Experience</li>
                <li id='menu-3'>Barter</li>
                <li id='menu-4'>Preview</li>
                <li id='menu-5'>About</li>
            </ul>


$(function() {
   var num = 460; //number of pixels before modifying styles
   var num2 = 2862;
   var num3 = 3715;
   var num4 = 4510;

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > num4)
    {   $('.pink-bar').addClass('fixed');
        $('#menu-5').addClass('ScrollNav');
        $('#menu-4, #menu-3, #menu-2,').removeClass('ScrollNav');


    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > num3)
    {   $('.pink-bar').addClass('fixed');
        $('#menu-4').addClass('ScrollNav');
        $('#menu-5, #menu-3, #menu-2 ').removeClass('ScrollNav');

    } else if  ($(window).scrollTop() > num2)
    {   $('.pink-bar').addClass('fixed');
        $('#menu-3').addClass('ScrollNav');
        $('#menu-4, #menu-5, #menu-2').removeClass('ScrollNav');

    } else if  ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.pink-bar').addClass('fixed');
        $('#menu-2').addClass('ScrollNav');
        $('#menu-3, #menu-5, #menu-3').removeClass('ScrollNav');

    }  else {
        $('.pink-bar').removeClass('fixed');
        $('#menu-2, #menu-3, #menu-4, #menu-5').removeClass('ScrollNav');
    }

    });

});
```

Comment: post sample to jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var num = $('#menu-1').offset().top;
var num2 = $('#menu-2').offset().top;
```

You may have to fiddle that slightly to take account of margins and borders depending on the style.

A better way would be to give all the menu items a single class, then loop through them all with `$('.menu-class').each(...)` and decide what to do given their (adjusted offset) and the current position. Which would make it extensible to more elements.